# RelativeSource not working using child property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, relativesource

I do not understand the issue / difference with the first binding with these examples:

(CustomTheme, ItemFormatting and FontNormal are DependencyObjects)

This one gets the error further down:

```
          NullToDependencyPropertyUnsetConverter unsetconv = new NullToDependencyPropertyUnsetConverter();

            Binding binding = new Binding("CustomTheme.ItemFormatting.FontNormal")
            {
                Converter = unsetconv,
                RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(ThemableUserControl), 2)
            };
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(itemsample.ItemFormatting, ItemFormatting.FontNormalProperty, binding);
```

This is an absolute equivalent of the first one and works:

```
     Binding binding = new Binding("CustomTheme.ItemFormatting.FontNormal")
            {
                Converter = unsetconv,
                Source = tucMain
            };
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(itemsample.ItemFormatting, ItemFormatting.FontNormalProperty, binding);
```

This is not what I want to achieve but works:

```
            Binding binding1 = new Binding("CustomTheme.ItemFormatting")
            {
                Converter = unsetconv,
                RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(ThemableUserControl), 2)
            };
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(itemsample, uc_item.ItemFormattingProperty, binding1);
```

I do not understand why I am getting the this output error on the first one:

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='AddonInterface.ThemableUserControl', AncestorLevel='2''. BindingExpression:Path=CustomTheme.ItemFormatting.FontNormal; DataItem=null; target element is 'ItemFormatting' (HashCode=43532274); target property is 'FontNormal' (type 'Font')

This is the window xaml.

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        xmlns:UIControls="clr-namespace:AddonInterface.UIControls;assembly=AddonInterface" xmlns:AddonInterface="clr-namespace:AddonInterface;assembly=AddonInterface"
    xmlns:uielements="clr-namespace:AddonInterface.UIElements;assembly=AddonInterface"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:CalcBinding;assembly=CalcBinding" x:Class="TestApp.SubthemeWidgetItem"
        mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="this"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="579.722" Width="1040.889" Loaded="This_Loaded" 
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    
    >
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/AddonInterface;component/Themes/defaultMainStyle.xaml"/>

    </Window.Resources>

    <AddonInterface:ThemableUserControl Name="tucMain" >
        <StackPanel>
            <AddonInterface:ThemableUserControl Name="tucSub" Height="225" Margin="0,0,604,0">
                <DockPanel Margin="0,0,-18,-41">


                    <Label Height="33">x) tuc2</Label>
                    <AddonInterface:AddonUserControl Name="aucSub" Margin="0,0,0,155" Width="147">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <Label Height="33">x) auc</Label>

                            <AddonInterface:uc_item  Name="itemsample" Title="x) item " />
                        </DockPanel>


                    </AddonInterface:AddonUserControl>


                </DockPanel>

            </AddonInterface:ThemableUserControl>


            <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Name="cbx2" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold">Toptheme</CheckBox>
            <UIControls:uc_themedesigner Visibility="{c:Binding ElementName=cbx2,Path=IsChecked}"  Name="mainwindowtheme"   />
            <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Name="cbx1" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold">Subtheme</CheckBox>
            <UIControls:uc_themedesigner Visibility="{c:Binding ElementName=cbx1,Path=IsChecked}" AllowNulls="True" Name="customtheme"    ></UIControls:uc_themedesigner>
            <Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click_1"/>





        </StackPanel>

    </AddonInterface:ThemableUserControl>



</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using AddonInterface;
using AddonInterface.DependencyObjects;
using AddonInterface.themes;
using AddonInterface.UIControls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SubthemeWidgetItem : Window
    {
        public SubthemeWidgetItem()
        {



            InitializeComponent();

            tucMain.CustomTheme = new dm_theme();
            tucMain.CustomTheme.ApplyAllDefault();
            tucMain.CustomTheme.ItemFormatting.FontNormal = new Font() { Size=60}; 
            tucSub.CustomTheme = new dm_theme();



            //BINDINGS THEME DESIGNER / TUC THEME
            mainwindowtheme.SetBinding(uc_themedesigner.ThemeDMProperty, new Binding("CustomTheme") { Source = tucMain });
            customtheme.SetBinding(uc_themedesigner.ThemeDMProperty, new Binding("CustomTheme") { Source = aucSub });


        

            this.Loaded += (a, b) =>
            {




                NullToDependencyPropertyUnsetConverter unsetconv = new NullToDependencyPropertyUnsetConverter();

                //Binding binding = new Binding("CustomTheme.ItemFormatting.FontNormal")
                //{
                //    Converter = unsetconv,
                //    RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(ThemableUserControl), 2)
                //};
                //BindingOperations.SetBinding(itemsample.ItemFormatting, ItemFormatting.FontNormalProperty, binding);



                Binding binding = new Binding("CustomTheme.ItemFormatting.FontNormal")
                {
                    Converter = unsetconv,
                    Source = tucMain
                };
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(itemsample.ItemFormatting, ItemFormatting.FontNormalProperty, binding);



                //Binding binding1 = new Binding("CustomTheme.ItemFormatting")
                //{
                //    Converter = unsetconv,
                //    RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(ThemableUserControl), 2)
                //};
                //BindingOperations.SetBinding(itemsample, uc_item.ItemFormattingProperty, binding1);




            };

            TestBorder = new dm_border() { Background = Brushes.Orange };

            this.DataContext = this;
        }





        public dm_border TestBorder
        {
            get { return (dm_border)GetValue(TestBorderProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TestBorderProperty, value);


            }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestBorderProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("TestBorder", typeof(dm_border), typeof(SubthemeWidgetItem),
     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(dm_border),
         FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
         new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTestBorderPropertyChanged)));


        private static void OnTestBorderPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SubthemeWidgetItem uci = sender as SubthemeWidgetItem;
            if (uci != null)
            {
                uci.OnTestBorderChanged();
            }
        }


        private void OnTestBorderChanged()
        {


        }




    }
}
```

thanks
Have a nice day

Comment: It's impossible to solve your problem without knowing the visual tree (DatContext, source, target). Obviously your binding source doesn't resolve. The first two snippets or binding declarations are not the _"absolute equivalent "_. That's why one works for you and the other doesn't. Note that setting `AncestorLevel` > 1 will skip the first (closest) encounter of the specified  `AncestorType`. If there is only one ancestor of `ThemableUserControl` then the binding would fail. The error message says it all: _"Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource"_.

Comment: Hi sorry for better overview:   Its 1: Path B & RelResource A,2:  PathB & Source A,3:  Path A & RelResource A. Only the combination in example 1 gives the error the other ones work. The relative resource  is verified in 3 as well as the Path in 2. I dont think a different path should have any effect on the relative resource right?

Comment: Please post the XAML that shows the binding target and the source or the related C# code if you don't use XAML. RelativeSource traverses the visual tree - from target to source. If RelativeSource doesn't resolve, then there must be some issue with your tree. Tree and binding obviously don't match. Snippet 1 and 3 both use the same RelativeSource but start from a different target. I assume the first code should use AncestorLevel=1 instead of 2. But I don't know because I don't know how your controls are arranged and you refuse to post the tree structure as I've asked you before.

Comment: sorry for my refusal. I have updated the question. I see now I had to mention that CustomTheme, ItemFormatting and FontNormal are DependencyObjects.

Comment: Thank you. Any reason why you avoid setting the bindings in XAML?

Comment: Also check the C# [Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines#in-this-section), especially the section _Capitalization Conventions_ and _General Naming Conventions_.  XAML namespace aliases are supposed to use _camelCasing_.

Comment: Much appreciated, I planed to read into it!  (yes, I want them to be in a helper class.)

Answer (score 0):

The first binding is wrong, as the target object is `itemSample`. `itemsample.ItemFormatting` is a property on `itemSample` and not an element of the visual tree. That's why `RelativeSource` can't be resolved by the XAML parser.

To make the `RelativeSource` binding using the same source as your second code version, you must change the `Binding.Path`.

Note that setting a binding on a nested property is not possible using `BindingOperations`. The binding must be set directly on the object that owns the target property. You can use `FrameworkElement.SetBinding` for this purpose.

The final binding would become:

**C#**

```
var unsetConv = new NullToDependencyPropertyUnsetConverter();

var binding = new Binding("CustomTheme.ItemFormatting.FontNormal")
{
  Converter = unsetConv,
  RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(ThemableUserControl), 2)
};

itemSample.ItemFormatting.SetBinding(ItemFormatting.FontNormalProperty, binding);
```

**XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
  <NullToDependencyPropertyUnsetConverter x:Key="NullToDependencyPropertyUnsetConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<AddonInterface:uc_item  Name="ItemSample" 
                         ItemFormatting="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ThemableUserControl, AncestorLevel=2}, 
                                                  Path=CustomTheme.ItemFormatting, 
                                                  Converter={StaticResource NullToDependencyPropertyUnsetConverter}}" />
```

Since you are using a named element as the binding source, you can also use the `Binding.ElementName` property instead:

```
<AddonInterface:uc_item  Name="ItemSample" 
                         ItemFormatting="{Binding Elementname=tucMain, 
                                                  Path=CustomTheme.ItemFormatting, 
                                                  Converter={StaticResource NullToDependencyPropertyUnsetConverter}}" />
```

Comment: I couldnt use this, setbinding is not a part of dependencyobject (at least not for my setup). I have ended up using an extension method getParent<> to find the themableusercontrol ancestor and setting it as source.

Comment: It's [`FrameworkElement.SetBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.setbinding?view=netframework-4.8) indeed. Anyway, it's available since .NET 3.0. Your solution is too complicated!

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up using an extension method getParent<> to find the themableusercontrol ancestor and setting it as source.